# Режим сна/гибернации при включенной записи в OBS

Tags: c#, windows, sleep

У меня есть приложение на C#, которое взаимодействует с OBS. Мне нужно как-то понимать, что Windows хочет перейти в режим сна или гибернации, для того, чтоб останавливать запись видео. Я хочу выяснить можно ли как-то понять, что Windows только собирается изменить режим.

PS: Пробовал привязаться к событию SystemEvents.PowerModeChanged. Это событие срабатывает, если системе ничего не мешает переключиться в режим сна/гибернации. Но при записи видео это событие не генерируется.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/a/2284720/12888024

Comment: @aepot, работает только с режимом гибернации

Comment: Как вы проверили?